# Setting document extensions in UIDocumentPicker in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I am using document picker for picking documents and upload on Server. All I need to pass some extension for the allowed documents, But I am not able to find out what extension represents to what type of document. Here is a list of extensions I want to allow.
        - docx - Microsoft Word
        - xlsx - Microsoft Excel
        - pptx - Microsoft Powerpoint
        - pdf 
        - csv
        - pages
        - numbers
        - key - Keynote
        - rtf
        - txt
i know some extensions like "kUTTypePDF,kUTTypeRTF", but not all please help.

Answer (score 6):

**Swift 5.0**

```
let types = [kUTTypePDF, kUTTypeText, kUTTypeRTF, kUTTypeSpreadsheet] // You can add more types here as pr your expectation
let importMenu = UIDocumentPickerViewController(documentTypes: types as [String], in: .import)
```

**Try this one**

If you want to select all files then you have to use following code:

```
let documentPicker = UIDocumentPickerViewController(documentTypes: ["com.apple.iwork.pages.pages", "com.apple.iwork.numbers.numbers", "com.apple.iwork.keynote.key","public.image", "com.apple.application", "public.item", "public.content", "public.audiovisual-content", "public.movie", "public.audiovisual-content", "public.video", "public.audio", "public.text", "public.data", "public.zip-archive", "com.pkware.zip-archive", "public.composite-content"], in: .import)
```

Comment: Thanks @Nikunj, But i want only selected files (- docx - Microsoft Word - xlsx - Microsoft Excel - pptx - Microsoft Powerpoint - pdf - csv - pages - numbers - key - Keynote - rtf - txt).

Answer (score 6):

For **.doc**, **.docx**, you can use **"com.microsoft.word.doc"**, **"org.openxmlformats.wordprocessingml.document"**

For **.xlsx**, you can use **"org.openxmlformats.spreadsheetml.sheet"**

For **.xls**, you can use **"com.microsoft.excel.xls"**

Answer (score 4):

Apple has posted a list of the built-in document types here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/UTIRef/Articles/System-DeclaredUniformTypeIdentifiers.html

I believe that should have all the ones you are looking for.  If not, then you'll have to add your own types.  You can do this by selecting the Project in Xcode and going into the Info tab.  Then at the bottom, add a new Imported UTI for each file type.

- Description:  User-friendly description
- Identifier:  This is the identifier you will use in the documentTypes parameter for UIDocumentPickerViewController.  com.yourcompany.yourproduct.fileextension or similar.
- Conforms to: "public.data, public.content"

Then under Additional Imported UTI properties click to add the following:

```
UTTypeTagSpecification (Dictionary)
    public.filename-extension (Array)
        Item 0 (String): the file extension without "." (i.e. "csv")
```

Comment: In Xcode 12 the section is called "Imported Type Identifiers"